# Remove elements in one array from another array in perl

Tags: perl

I want to get all elements in clearcase, store them in an array, and then remove the symbolic links from that array. Problem is I don't know how to remove all elements in one array that are contained in another array since I'm new to perl.

Bellow is my code so far.

```
foreach ${dir} (@{code_vob_list}) 
{
    ${dir} =~ s/\n//;
    open(FIND_FILES, "$cleartool find ${dir} -type f -exec 'echo \$CLEARCASE_PN' |") or die "Can't stat cleartool or execute : $!\n"; #This command gets all files
    @{files_found} = <FIND_FILES>;

    open(SYMBOLIC_FIND_FILES, "$cleartool find ${dir} -type l -exec 'echo \$CLEARCASE_PN' |") or die "Can't stat cleartool or execute : $!\n"; #This command get all symbolic links
    @{symbolic_files_found} = <SYMBOLIC_FIND_FILES>;
    #Filter away all strings contained in @{symbolic_files_found} from @{files_found}
    foreach my ${file} (@{files_found}) 
    {
        #Here I will perform my actions on @{files_found} that not contains any symbolic link paths from @{symbolic_files_found}
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you learn to put all your identifiers inside braces? I hope you realise that it's unnecessary, and I believe it makes the code less readable

Comment: Try looking at File::Find for tasks like this.

Answer (score 10):

To filter an array, you can use [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep):

```
my @nonlinks = grep { my $f = $_;
                      ! grep $_ eq $f, @symbolic_files_found }
               @files_found;
```

But it's usually cleaner to use a hash.

```
my %files;
@files{ @files_found } = ();            # All files are the keys.
delete @files{ @symbolic_files_found }; # Remove the links.
my @nonlinks = keys %files;
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you install and use [`List::Compare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare). The code would look like this

As I wrote in my comment, I'm not sure if you prefer to write your identifiers like that, and I'm also unclear if you've avoided backticks `` `...` `` (same as `qx{...}`) in favour of a pipe open for a reason, but this is closer to how I'd write your code

If you prefer, `get_unique` has a synonym `get_Lonly` which you may find more expressive

```
use List::Compare;

for my $dir ( @code_vob_list ) {

    chomp $dir;

    my @files_found = qx{$cleartool find $dir -type f -exec 'echo \$CLEARCASE_PN'};
    chomp @files_found;

    my @symbolic_files_found = qx{$cleartool find $dir -type l -exec 'echo \$CLEARCASE_PN'};
    chomp @symbolic_files_found;

    my $lc = List::Compare->new('--unsorted', \@files_found, \@symbolic_files_found);
    my @unique = $lc->get_unique;
}
```